# Chess engines' .dll files usable in C# projects

Tags: engines, programming

Are there any free/paid chess engine .dll files that could be used in a C# project as a reference?

Comment: Hi Andrius, questions that ask for products or software generally don't work well on Stack Exchange.  For more information, see [this Stack Exchange blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#?  Probably not any upper tier engines.  Chess engines tend to be written for speed and are largely written in C, C++, or assembly.

I googled and found [this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/cshuochess). And [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36112/Chess-Program-in-C). And [this](http://chessforeva.blogspot.com/2012/01/c-chess-engines.html).

Comment: This is wrong because the C# port in the other answer can be converted to a DLL file easily.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [C# port of Stockfish by bpfliegel](https://github.com/bpfliegel/Portfish). To my knowledge it is complete (was able to compile and run it) and even though it has not been updated in 11 months at the time of this post it is certainly much stronger than the other engines listed. When I tested its perft function it on my machine it was only a factor of 1.5 slower than the original C++ implementation.